# Fill the actual data with duplicated data and remove duplicated data

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

I have the following data:-

```
library(data.table)
data <- data <- data.table(address = c("AA", "BB", "AA", "CC", "DD", "EE", "DD"),
                   revenue = c(NA, 121, 22, 33, 44, 33, NA),
                   castord = c(21, 22, NA, 3, NA, 223, 33),
                   versaze = c(NA, 22, 124, 33, NA, 44, 43))
data

#    address revenue castord versaze
# 1:      AA      NA      21      NA
# 2:      BB     121      22      22
# 3:      AA      22      NA     124
# 4:      CC      33       3      33
# 5:      DD      44      NA      NA
# 6:      EE      33     223      44
# 7:      DD      NA      33      43
```

Now this data has `AA` and `DD` `address`es duplicated. And their first occurrence has some `NA` data as you can see in the row `1` and `5`. What I want to do is fill this data by using the duplicated rows of these `address`es. If the duplicated row has NA values, then NA shouldn't replace the values in the row of first occurrence. This will give me the following data:-

```
    data <- data.table(address = c("AA", "BB", "AA", "CC", "DD", "EE", "DD"),
                   revenue = c(22, 121, 22, 33, 44, 33, NA),
                   castord = c(21, 22, NA, 3, 33, 223, 33),
                   versaze = c(124, 22, 124, 33, 43, 44, 43))

#    address revenue castord versaze
# 1:      AA      22      21     124
# 2:      BB     121      22      22
# 3:      AA      22      NA     124
# 4:      CC      33       3      33
# 5:      DD      44      33      43
# 6:      EE      33     223      44
# 7:      DD      NA      33      43
```

And then remove those duplicated rows:-

```
data <- data.table(address = c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE"),
                   revenue = c(22, 121, 33, 44, 33),
                   castord = c(21, 22, 3, 33, 223),
                   versaze = c(124, 22, 33, 43, 44))

#    address revenue castord versaze
# 1:      AA      22      21     124
# 2:      BB     121      22      22
# 3:      CC      33       3      33
# 4:      DD      44      33      43
# 5:      EE      33     223      44
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using *data.table*, group by address, loop through columns, remove NAs, get the first value:

```
data[, lapply(.SD, function(i) (na.omit(i)[ 1 ])), by = address]
#    address revenue castord versaze
# 1:      AA      22      21     124
# 2:      BB     121      22      22
# 3:      CC      33       3      33
# 4:      DD      44      33      43
# 5:      EE      33     223      44
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `dplyr::group_by` and `summarise` where you take the first value that is not `NA` using `na.omit`, it fills out the empty values for you if the first row is `NA`.

```
data <- data %>% group_by(address) %>% 
  summarise(
    revenue = first(na.omit(revenue)),
    castord = first(na.omit(castord)),
    versaze = first(na.omit(versaze))
    )
```

Comment: Is there a `data.table` way to do this?

Comment: Not that I know of and nothing I could skim in their documentation. Why is it a problem to use dplyr/tidyverse?

Comment: Actually the real table I have is very large around 900 mb and I wanted to use `data.table` to keep it as memory efficient as possible.